# Toggling an item in nested list expands/collapses the whole list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-lists

I am making a nested list using react where list has objects with each having attribute `name` and `children`. For instance:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "elementName",
        "children": [{
            "name": "elementName",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": "2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am making the list in a way that as long as an object has attribute `children`, print its name. I want to toggle the child nodes based on the click on parent node but since I am mapping the child nodes inside the same `<div>` I am printing the `name` of parent node, I am not getting how to toggle the child nodes. Here's my code:

In constructor of the current component:

```
this.state = {
      visibility: false,
};
```

Here's where I render an item ultimately calling upon `ListItem` component:

```
renderChild = (mappingItem) => {
    var style;
    if (!this.state.visibility) {
       style = {display: "none"};
    }
    if(mappingItem.children){
      return (
       <div>
          <h5 onClick={this.toggle}><ListItem {...mappingItem} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(...)}/></h5>
          <ul style={style}>
            {mappingItem.children.map(item => {
              return this.renderChild(item);
            })}
          </ul>
       </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
 }

toggle = () => {
    this.setState({visibility: !this.state.visibility});
  };
```

And in the `ListItem` component:

```
render() {
   return (
        <li>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
          />
          {this.props.name}
        </li>
      );
  }
```

So far when I click on a parent node, all the children of all parent nodes expand, i.e the whole list. And when I uncheck the parent node or any other node for that matter, the whole list collapses. How can I fix this? I would appreciate some help figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

Put style variable as part of ListItem component state and pass it from the parent node. Because there is only one 'style/visiblity' instance which is used by all of ListItems they behave similarly.

Earlier answer was misleading I meant style only not the this.toggle which is a method. All I want to say is have a separate style/visibility variable instance for every ListItem.

Create a codePen or something, I can do that.

Comment: Where would the variable `style` be placed?

Comment: What this essentially means that this.state.visibility is the state of parent of ListItem's which is single instance. We need to have visibility for every ListItem because it is ListItem's state.

Comment: Could you please show it on CodePen, @suryapratap? Here's is it: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYKYgm)

Comment: Thanks a lot but the root element's name goes completely invisible.